# Synchronous MMF Test

Tags: .net, vb.net, architecture

I'm seeking some second opinions regarding the validity of my test.

In a nutshell, I'm using MMF to simulate a synchronous method call from a WinForms client to a Windows Service. Neither WCF nor Named Pipes is a good fit for this, due to the reasons discussed [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/b83c8f10-fbe4-47bc-9652-7f4a0715c39a/).

For my prototype I've created two simple applications--a console app represents the WinForms 'client' and a WinForms app represents the WinService 'server.'

I've had to overcome two main problems: 1) The server's timer fires only once every three seconds, and 2) The OS seems to require at least a full second to acquire and then release a mutex. This second point has got me curious. I'd have thought the process was instant, but apparently I'm mistaken.

To accomodate these two issues I've used Thread.Sleep--two seconds to wait for the server's timer and one second to wait for the mutex handling. Intervals of any less than these cause intermittent read/write synchronization failures. Of course feel free to tweak the code to get your own results.

My test is comprised of a 30,000-iteration loop in the client that 'calls' the 'method' in the server and writes the response to a log file. Currently I'm at iteration ~22,500 without any error.

My question: does anyone see any problems with my test? Given the requirements indicated in my MSDN post (linked above), do my results so far indicate a stable design?

That said, if my architecture can be improved I'd be very interested to hear about it.

Here's the code:

*Console (client)*

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Security.Cryptography

Module Main
  Sub Main()
    Dim _
      sForward,
      sReverse,
      sOutput As String

    Console.WriteLine("Enter a string to reverse:")

    For iCount As Integer = 0 To 29999
      sForward = GetRandomString(7)
      sReverse = ReverseString(sForward)
      sOutput = sForward & " => " & sReverse

      File.AppendAllText("Output.log", sOutput & vbCrLf)

      Console.WriteLine(sOutput)
      Thread.Sleep(1000)
    Next

    Console.ReadLine()
  End Sub

  Private Function GetRandomString(Length As Integer) As String
    Dim sSeedText As String
    Dim oBuilder As StringBuilder
    Dim aBuffer As Byte()
    Dim oCrypto As RNGCryptoServiceProvider

    sSeedText = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    oBuilder = New StringBuilder
    aBuffer = New Byte(Length - 1) {}
    oCrypto = New RNGCryptoServiceProvider

    oCrypto.GetNonZeroBytes(aBuffer)

    For Each bByte As Byte In aBuffer
      oBuilder.Append(sSeedText.Chars(bByte Mod sSeedText.Length))
    Next

    Return oBuilder.ToString
  End Function

  Private Function ReverseString(Data As String) As String
    Dim lIsOwner As Boolean
    Dim iLength As Integer
    Dim aData As Byte()

    aData = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(Data)
    iLength = aData.Length

    Using oFile As MemoryMappedFile = MemoryMappedFile.CreateNew("{99EC7026-0059-4D48-99B1-B400BDACBDD8}", 1024)
      Using oMutex As New Mutex(True, "{35C4F5C6-874B-4536-901A-D5382B7E2B9C}", lIsOwner)
        '*=====================================================================
        '  Wait for the server's Timer.Tick event to fire
        '*=====================================================================
        Thread.Sleep(2000)
        '*=====================================================================

        Using oStream As MemoryMappedViewStream = oFile.CreateViewStream(0, 0)
          Using oWriter As New BinaryWriter(oStream)
            oWriter.Write(iLength)
            oWriter.Write(aData)
          End Using
        End Using

        oMutex.ReleaseMutex()

        '*=====================================================================
        '  Wait for the server to acquire and then release the mutex
        '*=====================================================================
        Thread.Sleep(1000)
        '*=====================================================================

        oMutex.WaitOne()

        Using oStream As MemoryMappedViewStream = oFile.CreateViewStream(iLength + 4, 0)
          Using oReader As New BinaryReader(oStream)
            With oReader
              aData = .ReadBytes(.ReadInt32)
            End With
          End Using
        End Using

        oMutex.ReleaseMutex()
      End Using
    End Using

    Return Encoding.Unicode.GetString(aData)
  End Function
End Module
```

*WinForms (server)*

```
'*=============================================================================
'
'   Add a ListBox
'   Add a Background Worker
'   Add a Windows Forms Timer
'     Interval = 3000
'     Enabled = True
'
'*=============================================================================

Imports System.IO
Imports System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.Text

Public Class Main
  Private Sub tmrTimer_Tick(Sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tmrTimer.Tick
    Dim lIsOpen As Boolean
    Dim oFile As MemoryMappedFile

    tmrTimer.Stop()

    Try
      lIsOpen = True
      oFile = MemoryMappedFile.OpenExisting("{99EC7026-0059-4D48-99B1-B400BDACBDD8}")
      bgwWorker.RunWorkerAsync(oFile)

    Catch ex As FileNotFoundException
      lIsOpen = False

    End Try

    If Not lIsOpen Then
      tmrTimer.Start()
    End If
  End Sub

  Private Sub bgwWorker_DoWork(Sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles bgwWorker.DoWork
    Dim iLength As Integer
    Dim sData As String
    Dim aData As Byte()

    Using oFile As MemoryMappedFile = e.Argument
      Using oMutex As Mutex = Mutex.OpenExisting("{35C4F5C6-874B-4536-901A-D5382B7E2B9C}")
        oMutex.WaitOne()

        Using oStream As MemoryMappedViewStream = oFile.CreateViewStream(0, 0)
          Using oReader As New BinaryReader(oStream)
            With oReader
              aData = .ReadBytes(.ReadInt32)
            End With
          End Using
        End Using

        sData = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(aData)
        aData = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(New String(sData.Reverse.ToArray))
        iLength = aData.Length

        Using oStream As MemoryMappedViewStream = oFile.CreateViewStream(iLength + 4, 0)
          Using oWriter As New BinaryWriter(oStream)
            oWriter.Write(iLength)
            oWriter.Write(aData)
          End Using
        End Using

        oMutex.ReleaseMutex()
      End Using
    End Using

    e.Result = sData
  End Sub

  Private Sub bgwWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(Sender As Object, e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles bgwWorker.RunWorkerCompleted
    lstArguments.Items.Add(e.Result)
    tmrTimer.Start()
  End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Is that "single client-single server" approach? Otherwise how are you going to maintain multiple clients? And the other question - can't you handle listener timeouts in WCF or Named pipes? Actually my previous experience with IPC via MMF shows tendency to over engineering.

Comment: Yes, single client/single server. WCF requires a port, which leaves it out (see MSDN post). It only recently occurred to me that I could handle a Named Pipes fault by running a NET START process to restart the service; by the time I thought of it I'd already worked up this solution. It took quite a bit of engineering to get to this point. Based on your MMF experience, would you consider this over engineered? Do you see any fault with my testing approach?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "WCF requires a port". WCF is a communication abstraction. For local processes it uses named pipes, which in turn are built with shared memory. Apart of that your code looks ok for sample. You don't have to remap file each time you read/write. And you should use events instead of that pretty "Thread.Sleep(2000).

Comment: Yes, you're correct. I was thinking of WCF in terms of BasicHTTPBinding. I Googled 'named pipes timeout' and there seems to be a common problem there. At least this solution works at this time. You say "OK for sample." Do you have any suggestions for production improvement? Also how would you implement an event to replace Thread.Sleep? I agree, I don't like it either.

Comment: All right, but I suggest that you submit this question to http://codereview.stackexchange.com - it's specifically for such comments.

Comment: @mikalai - Got it posted over there, thanks for the tip. (http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/17763/synchronous-mmf-test) Wasn't aware of that site. I'm still interested in your thoughts about production improvements and `Event` vs. `Thread.Sleep()`. Would very much like to hear from you on these if you get a chance.